# Problem with counting dynamic allocation. C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Hey I have written code and I don't know why it is not working, it suppose to count number of memory reservations but I have done something wrong (I mean no of memory allocations is equal to `0` in both counters) and I can't spot the problem, I will appreciate any help. First post here so please be patient. :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
struct A
{
    int a;
    static int nr;
    void * operator new[](std::size_t n) {++nr; return ::new char[n]; }
};
struct B
{
    double b;
    static int nr;
    void * operator new[](std::size_t n) {++nr; return ::new char[n]; }
};
int A::nr = 0, B::nr = 0;
int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vecA;
    std::vector<B> vecB;
    for (int i{}; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        vecA.push_back(A());
        vecB.push_back(B());
    }
    cout << "Size of vecA: " << vecA.size() * sizeof(A) << ", number of times that memory was allocated: " << A::nr << endl;
    cout << "Size of vecB: " << vecB.size() * sizeof(B) << ", number of times that memory was allocated: " << B::nr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is never calling your own `new[]` - at what point did you expect it to be called and why?

Comment: I'd suspect with the code you're using your overloaded `new` operator never will be called at all.

Comment: [mcve] also means to tell what you expect and what you got. You don't tell what exactly is different from what you expect. I guess you mean that the output is `0` for both counters!?

Comment: Do you need to actually know how many times memory is allocated, or just how many times your object is constructed?

Comment: I thought that if I will be pushing new structures at the end of the vector, then at some point it will allocate more memory because at the beginning it has relatively small space allocated.

Comment: Phil M I want to know how many times memory is allocated

Comment: vectors dont allocate memory for single instances. To comply with the complexity constraint for adding elements, they have to allocate memory in chuncks, where each chunck is bigger than the previous one. I dont know a reliable way to count the number of allocations a vector does.

Comment: maybe try to see what the vectors `capacity` is after each push back.

Comment: Your std::vector seems to use something other than new[] to allocate memory, probably malloc.

Comment: urks removed the last sentence from previous comment because it was wrong. What I mean to say is that vectors typically double their capacity when it is needed (and my calculation to arrive at the total number of allocations was way off)

Comment: You could try to provide your own [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) to `std::vector` which tracks the amount of allocations (but it seems overkill IMO)

Comment: @user463035818 no. of allocations should be in the range of 10-13 (or so I think :D ).  I've checked capacity and it's changing.

Comment: @pschill: Due to implementation requirements on vector, it's probably using `new char[buffer_size]`, and then using placement new to construct instances. Neither of which uses any version of `A::operator new`.

Answer (score 3):

To count the number of memory reallocation I only see creation of own allocator class. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class countingAllocator : public std::allocator<T>
{
public:

   template<typename _Tp1>
   struct rebind
   {
      typedef countingAllocator<_Tp1> other;
   };

   T* allocate(size_t n, const void *hint = 0)
   {
      T::nr++;
      return std::allocator<T>::allocate(n, hint);
   }

   countingAllocator() : std::allocator<T>()
   { }

   countingAllocator(const countingAllocator &a) : std::allocator<T>(a)
   { }

   template <class U>
   countingAllocator(const countingAllocator<U> &a) : std::allocator<T>(a)
   { }
   ~countingAllocator()
   { }
};

// Fix for VS Debug build Don`t need for Release
template <>
class countingAllocator<std::_Container_proxy> : public 
  std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>
{
public:
   template <class U>
   countingAllocator(const countingAllocator<U> &a) : 
     std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>(a)
   { }
};


std::vector<A, countingAllocator<A>> vecA;
std::vector<B, countingAllocator<B>> vecB;
for (int i{}; i < 1000; i++)
{
    vecA.push_back(A());
    vecB.push_back(B());
}
```

Output:

```
Size of vecA: 4000, number of times that memory was allocated: 18
Size of vecB: 8000, number of times that memory was allocated: 18
```

Comment: @BJagger, confirm if my last understanding of your question is correct. I will try to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    static int nr;
};

struct B
{
    double b;
    static int nr;
};

int A::nr = 0, B::nr = 0;

int main ()
{
    std::vector<A> vecA;
    std::vector<B> vecB;
    size_t A_capacity = 0, B_capacity = 0;

    for (int i{}; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        vecA.push_back(A());
        if (vecA.capacity () != A_capacity)
        {
            ++A::nr;
            A_capacity = vecA.capacity ();
        }

        vecB.push_back(B());
        if (vecB.capacity () != B_capacity)
        {
            ++B::nr;
            B_capacity = vecB.capacity ();
        }
    }

    std::cout << "A: " << A::nr << ", B: " << B::nr;
}
```

Output:

```
A: 11, B: 11
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/owBjcFrj15hdvUCu)